# How to load multiple parameters Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I want to load multiple parameters when a job starts, like:
 Key A = value a
 Key B = value b

Is there a plugin that can do that from a file  or a script?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Please note that from version 2.3 there is security issue 170 that prevents injecting parameters between jobs so you'll need to inject this file in all jobs or add an exception in the Jenkins service